# How do I get a callback from a SpriteKit repeating action when the sprite reaches the end of a path?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skaction, skspritenode

I have created my `SKAction` in this manner:

```
unicornAction = [SKAction followPath:mypath asOffset:NO orientToPath:YES duration:0.1];
```

and added it to my `SKSprite`:

```
[sprite runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:unicornAction] withKey:@"move"];
```

I do this so that I can adjust the speed at any time within the sprites motion across the path.

**When my sprite gets to the end of the path, I need a callback so that I can remove the sprite. How can I get such a callback?**

Also, is there a better way of using `SKAction` to do what I am trying to do, while allowing me to change the speed anywhere during the actions run?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a sequence with a runBlock or performSelector at the end:

```
SKAction* sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[unicornAction, [SKAction runBlock:^{
    // code at end of path goes here...
}]];
```

You can also use

```
[sprite runAction:sequence withKey:@"follow path"];
```

and later get the action by key:

```
SKAction* sequence = [sprite actionForKey:@"follow path"];
```

Comment: This worked a lot nicer than I thought I thought it would have. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a second runBlock: action that does whatever you want it to do when the action finishes, then create a sequence: action with your followPath and block finishing actions.  If you don't want to use a block there's also a performSelector:onTarget: action.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/Reference/Reference.html